# Minimize returns strange root objects

Tags: mathematical-optimization, geometry

I am using `Minimize` to find a solution for the following set of equations that minimizes my cost function $c + k\cdot r$:

[image: Set of equations]

Essentially, I have two points $p_1,p_2$ with x coordinates $r$ and $2r$ and initial y coordinates $0$ and $r$ that I can move upwards to a new position $p_1=(r, r\cdot k), p_2=(2r,r + r\cdot k)$ in the y direction. I am looking for a $k$ that minimizes the shortest distance $|p_1q|+|p_2q|$ to a point $q=(x,y)$ on a circle $C$ centered at $(x_0,y_0)=(0,2r)$ with radius $r$. For a given $k$ the point can be found when calculating the intersection point between my fixed circle and the ellipse $E$, centered at $(x_e,y_e)$ induced by $p_1,p_2$:
$$x_e = \frac{1}{2}(p^x_1 + p^x_2) = \frac{3}{2}r$$
$$y_e = \frac{1}{2}(p^y_1 + p^y_2) = \frac{1}{2}(r+2kr)$$
Let $f$ be the distance from the center point of $E$ to the foci
$$f=\sqrt{(p^x_1-x_e)^2 + (p^y_1-y_e)^2} = \sqrt{\frac{r^2}{4} + \frac{(r+kr)^2}{4}} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{k \cdot (k+2) + 2}r$$
The ellipse can now be defined with its center point $(x_e,y_e)$ and the major/minor axis $a,b$.
$$a= \frac{1}{2} c$$
$$b= \sqrt{a^2 - f^2} = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{c^2 - (k \cdot (k+2) + 2)r^2}$$

In order to find the minimal solution, I assumed that $r=1$ to simplify the formulas above:

```
Dist[x_, y_, z_, v_] := Sqrt[(x - z)^2 + (y - v)^2]
r = 1;
xPos[k_] := 3/2* r
yPos[k_] := 1/2 * (r + k*r)
f[k_] := Dist[xPos[k], yPos[k], r, r*k] 

a[c_, k_] := 1/2 * c
b[c_, k_] := Sqrt[a[c, k]^2 - f[k]^2] 

res = Minimize[{c + k*r, x^2 + (y - 2 *r)^2 == r^2 && (x - xPos[k])^2/a[c, k]^2 + (y - 
yPos[k])^2/b[c, k]^2 == 1 && 0 <= k <= 1 && c == Dist[x, y, r, k*r] +  Dist[x, y, 2 r, r + 
k*r] && 0 <= x <= r && r <= y <= 2 r && c > 0 }, {c, x, y, k }, Reals]
```

I am sure that this might not be the most elegant solution but after a few hours of computation I get the following result:

[image: Result of Minimization]

As you can see in the image all values for $x,y,k,c,cost$ are `Root` objects. I am fine that Mathematica gives me these objects instead of a closed form, but I am worried that my Minimization has an error, because all `Root` objects have exponents up to $128$ with very strange factors. Here is for example the beginning of the polynom for $k$:
$$8837684323394741881152434292665551758032896 - 438169602476233057174556091222444606626988032*x + ... $$

As all of my variables have these kinds of factors and all roots have exponents up to 128, my guess is that `Minimize` uses some numerical approximations that produce these strange numbers and that the precision is somehow limited to an exponent of $128$. I also plotted the Root polynom for $k$ between $0.48$ and $0.49$ which confuses me even more:

[image: Plot for the polynom of k]

Are there different approaches that I can use to verify my result or techniques to simplify my input formulas? I am assuming that this behavior has something to do with the strange form of $c$ that is the sum of two square roots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Dist[x_, y_, z_, v_] := Sqrt[(x - z)^2 + (y - v)^2]
r = 1;
xPos[k_] := 3/2*r
yPos[k_] := 1/2*(r + k*r)
f[k_] := Dist[xPos[k], yPos[k], r, r*k]

a[c_, k_] := 1/2*c
b[c_, k_] := Sqrt[a[c, k]^2 - f[k]^2]

sys = {c + k*r, 
   x^2 + (y - 2*r)^2 == 
     r^2 && (x - xPos[k])^2/a[c, k]^2 + (y - yPos[k])^2/b[c, k]^2 == 1 && 
    0 <= k <= 1 && c == Dist[x, y, r, k*r] + Dist[x, y, 2 r, r + k*r] && 
    0 <= x <= r && r <= y <= 2 r && c > 0};
```

Since you said that your results took "a few hours of computation", I have verified with a numeric result.

```
resN = NMinimize[sys, {c, x, y, k}, WorkingPrecision -> 30] // N

(* {2.6338, {c -> 2.15115, x -> 0.848236, y -> 1.47038, k -> 0.482657}} *)
```

The numeric results agree with the values shown in the picture of your `Root` expressions

Verifying that the result satisfies the system

```
(sys[[1]] == resN[[1]] && Rest[sys]) /. resN[[2]]

(* {True} *)
```

You don't show the code that you used for your `Plot`; however, I assume that you used machine precision. Since the `Root` expressions have coefficients as large as you show, then a large `WorkingPrecision` is required to maintain precision. Start with `WorkingPrecision -> 75`. Increase if required.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I plotted again with the new working precision and it seems to work just fine. Do you think that there is any hope to find another representation of my number (maybe using a completely different approach) or is the fact that Mathematica gave me this root object the proof that there is no "nicer" representation of my number (which might include sin, cos, tan, pi etc.)?

Comment: @michip96 - the result for `c` has two `Root` functions. `RootReduce` should be able to combine them into a single `Root` function. I don't know what order the polynomials are, but at least for low-order polynomials, `ToRadicals` can convert `Root` functions to radical form. Otherwise, `Root` functions are pretty compact ways of representing exact results.

Comment: `ToRadicals` did not change the `Root` objects add all. The problem is that I would like to add the exact values of these objects to my thesis, but the factors of the polynomial are so long that their full expansion uses more than three pages. I found that `RootApproximant` gives me a good approximation. However, I am curious if I can find a better representation of the exact number.

Comment: @michip96 - Put the long form root expressions in an appendix. For the body use `sol//N[#,75]//N`. The first `N` ensures precision in the result, the second `N` shortens the precise value for display.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will shorten the polynomials as you suggested.